# What is a coefficient?

Tags: mathematics

I am having hard trouble learning about coefficients and constants. Please give me a specific example or answer. I think that a coefficient is a number after a variable. Also I believe that Constants are the number after a + or - sign.

Comment: I really don't understand and I have a exam tommorrow. Please answer!

Comment: Your answer would have a non-negligible chance to survive on the http://physics.stackexchange.com, although your comment below had significantly reduced it.

Comment: As Morning star said, you've not really come to the right place for this (though [mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) may have been a better place for this). We are a world building site for questions on the creation of fictional worlds. You are, however, welcome to post a question along those lines instead.

Comment: good username though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Constant: a value given by some external source and doesn't change. For example, on the Earth, the strength of the gravity is constant.
- Coefficient: "co" means "with", "efficient" means here "is effecting". It is a value which describes, how something changes with an other thing. For example, the *barometric coefficient* shows, how the air pressure decreases if you fly higher.

Comment: @SavageCabbage There is a pipe icon on the left, if you click it, it is to me a reward. :-)

Comment: where, Morning Star?

Comment: @SavageCabbage To the left or my text, just below the "0". Thanks! :-) It is also useful to show for others, that the question is already answered.

Comment: I clicked the check mark. Is it, it?

Comment: @SavageCabbage Yes. Nota bene (latinic word, it means "good remark"), the site is quite useful for you, and there are also a lot of similar [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites). We get points for answering questions, and also for asking questions. Furthermore, many questions and many answers are very interesting and it is quite fun to asking, answering and moderating them. It is a little bit addicting.

Comment: I find it addicting too!

Comment: Does your reputation restart everyday?

Comment: Just wondering.

Comment: @SavageCabbage No. The rules are these: For an upvote to a question, you get 5. For an upvote to an answer, you get 10. If you accept an answer, you get 2. If somebody accepts your answer, you get 15. For any downvote, you lose 2. Your reputation can't go below 1. I voted your question up (+5), you accepted my answer (+2), but also you've got 7 downvotes to your question meanwhile (-14), because they've considered it off-topic. Thus, your reputation went back to 1. But don't worry, also I've started so :-) Your next posts will be much more successful.